# How can I process a Perl array element in a shell script?

Tags: perl, bash

For example:

In Perl:

```
@array = (1,2,3);

system ("/tmp/a.sh @array" );
```

In my shell script, how do I handle this array in shell script? How do I handle the shell script to receive the arguments, and how do I use that array variable in shell script?

Comment: You're going to have to give some more detail. What do you mean by "handle"? What do you expect the shell script to receive as arguments?

Comment: I dont know to how recive the perl array arguments

Comment: do you want to pass all the array elements to bash script?

Comment: Yes . I want to pass all elements into bash script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
my @array = (1,2,3);   
system ("/tmp/a.sh @array" );
```

is equivalent to the shell command:

```
/tmp/a.sh 1 2 3
```

you can see this by simply printing out what you pass to system:

```
print "/tmp/a.sh @array";
```

`a.sh` should handle them like any other set of shell arguments.

To be safe, you should bypass the shell and pass the array in as arguments directly:

```
system "/tmp/a.sh", @array;
```

Doing this passes each element of `@array` in as a separate argument rather than as a space separated string.  This is important if the values in `@array` contain spaces, for example:

```
my @array = ("Hello, world", "This is one argument");
system "./count_args.sh @array";
system "./count_args.sh", @array;
```

where `count_args.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$# arguments"
```

you'll see that in the first one it gets 6 arguments and the second it gets 2.

A short tutorial on handling arguments in a shell program can be found [here](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html).

Anyhow, why write one program in Perl and one in shell?  It increases complexity to use two languages and shell has no debugger.  Write them both in Perl.  Better yet, write it as a function in the Perl program.

Comment: Does passing as separate arguments to system also help when there are other "special" characters like quotes?  I have a syscall right now that is just escaping all the special characters to pass as a single string to system, but I'm wondering if passing as distinct args to system() would make it work w/o the escapes.

Comment: @Herms: Yes, by passing an array instead of a single string, you don't have to "escape" or quote the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The shell script receives its arguments in `$@`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# also works for Bash
for arg  # "in $@" is implied
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

In Bash, they can also be accessed using array subscripts or slicing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${@:2:1}"    # second argument
args=($@)
echo "${args[2]}"  # second argument
echo "${@: -1}"    # last argument
echo "${@:$#}"     # last argument
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

in Perl:

```
   @a=qw/aa bb cc/;
   system("a.sh ".join(' ',@a));
```

in shell (a.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1;
while test "$1"
do
    echo argument number $i = $1
    shift
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: It's better to use the list form of Perl's system. You can just say `system( 'a.sh', @a )`

Comment: It's better to use the list form of `system` *unless* you actually want shell interpolation of your arguments.  In that case, it's probably better to design your code so that you don't need it and can use the list form of `system`.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to pass all array elements once:

```
my @array = qw(1 2 3);

system("/tmp/a.sh". join(" ", @array));
```

If you want to pass array elements one by one:

```
my @array = qw(1 2 3);
foreach my $arr (@array) {
     system("/tmp/a.sh $arr");
}
```

Comment: How to handle this array variable in shell script ?

Comment: Unless someone has mucked with `$"`, `"@array"` is equivalent to `join(" ", @array)`

Comment: You don't need that join, and you should use system in the list form.